# how to show Progress Dialog in Non-Activity class inside list view

Tags: android, android-activity, progressdialog

I have adapter class for Listview that is inside a class which is name AdapterItems that extended in ArrayAdapter.

know how can I use progress dialog in this class that isn't extended in Activity?

this is my fill method for listview

```
public void fill(final ArrayAdapter<RssParser.Item> adapter, final RssParser.Item item, final int position)
    {

        Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {

                ActivityStartup.handler.post(new Runnable() {

                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        ActivityStartup.dismissLoadingDialog();
                        txtTitle.setText(item.title);
                        txtDate.setText(item.pubDate);
                        txt_time.setText(item.time);
                        txtDescription.setText(item.description);
                        layoutRoot.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                            @Override
                            public void onClick(View v) {

                                if (progress == null) {
                                    progress = new ProgressDialog(v.getContext());
                                    progress.setTitle("title");
                                    progress.setMessage("loading");
                                }
                                progress.show();
                                G.SelectedApplication = item;

                                Intent intent = new Intent(G.context, Adapter_Description.class)
                                        .setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                                intent.putExtra("INPUT", item.link + "");
                                intent.putExtra("INPUT_DESC", item.description + "");
                                G.context.startActivity(intent);
                            }
                        });

                    }
                });
            }
        });
        thread.start();

    }
}
```

when I clicked on the items on the list view to see the dialog I got a crash and this is my Log

> 09-06 12:04:10.368: E/AndroidRuntime(5112):   FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>   09-06 12:04:10.368: E/AndroidRuntime(5112):  android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token null is not for an application
>   09-06 12:04:10.368: E/AndroidRuntime(5112):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.setView(ViewRootImpl.java:571)
>   09-06 12:04:10.368: E/AndroidRuntime(5112):     at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:246)
>   09-06 12:04:10.368: E/AndroidRuntime(5112):     at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:69)
>   09-06 12:04:10.368: E/AndroidRuntime(5112):     at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:281)
>   09-06 12:04:10.368: E/AndroidRuntime(5112):     at com.myApp.course.app.feed_reader.AdapterItems$ViewHolder$1$1$1.onClick(AdapterItems.java:71)
>   09-06 12:04:10.368: E/AndroidRuntime(5112):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4204)
>   09-06 12:04:10.368: E/AndroidRuntime(5112):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17355)
>   09-06 12:04:10.368: E/AndroidRuntime(5112):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
>   09-06 12:04:10.368: E/AndroidRuntime(5112):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
>   09-06 12:04:10.368: E/AndroidRuntime(5112):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
>   09-06 12:04:10.368: E/AndroidRuntime(5112):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
>   09-06 12:04:10.368: E/AndroidRuntime(5112):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>   09-06 12:04:10.368: E/AndroidRuntime(5112):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
>   09-06 12:04:10.368: E/AndroidRuntime(5112):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
>   09-06 12:04:10.368: E/AndroidRuntime(5112):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
>   09-06 12:04:10.368: E/AndroidRuntime(5112):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
>   09-06 12:04:36.292: E/InputDispatcher(467):  channel 'a69034a0 com.myApp.course.app.feed_reader/com.myApp.course.app.feed_reader.ActivityStartup (server)' ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just pass the Activity `Context` to the Constructor of your non_activity class , then use that context to show your `ProgressDialog`

```
private Activity activityContext;

Public YourClassName(Activity activityContext)
{
  this.activityContext = activityContext;
}
```

then use this Context to initialize a ProgressDialog :

```
progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(activityContext);
```

Comment: how ? i'm new in android

Comment: I did but know I have error on this method : Implicit super constructor ArrayAdapter<RssParser.Item>() is undefined. Must explicitly invoke another constructor

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass

> Activity Context

to your non activity class. And then use that context to display Dialog